# Missing argument error in PHP

Tags: php

my error is:

**Missing argument 4 for azexo_nav_menu_link_attributes()**

and this is my code:

```
function azexo_nav_menu_link_attributes($atts, $item, $args, $depth) {
if (strpos($atts['title'], 'mega') !== false) {
    $atts['title'] = str_replace('mega', '', $atts['title']);
    $atts['href'] = '#';
}
$atts['class'] = 'menu-link';
return $atts;
```

How can i fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps when you call the function add the $depth parameter as an argument?

Comment: Show the call code.

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Show us that code.

Comment: I've fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where is the rest of your code? We need to see where is the call function.

Anyway, you should missing the 4th argument **$depth** when you call the function.

You may pass four arguments to the function as follows: `azexo_nav_menu_link_attributes($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)` instead `azexo_nav_menu_link_attributes($param1,$param2,$param3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last argument to be optional, you must set it up some value. try this:

```
function azexo_nav_menu_link_attributes($atts, $item, $args, $depth = null){ ... }
```

So you will be able to call your function and send just the 3 first parameters, or the 4 parameters. Depends of what you need.